# Grid adding unwanted extra vertical space

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following xaml inside a user control:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid Background="LimeGreen">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Yellow" Width="80" Height="80" />

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

and it produces the following layout:

[image: extra space]

For some reason, this is adding extra unwanted space after the yellow square. I want the following layout instead:

[image: correct]

The extra space only occurs when the green grid is inside a stack panel. I can get the correct layout by either:

- Putting the green grid inside a grid instead of a stack panel.
- Or setting the width of the second column to "Auto". This is undesired, though.

My questions are:

1. Is the layout in the first picture correct/expected? If so, why is it adding the extra space?
2. Why does setting the *width* of the second column to "Auto" get rid of the extra *vertical* space?
3. How can I get layout #2 inside a stack panel with width of second column set to * (star)?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer question 3 with this alternative xaml, however it uses a nested grid to bypass using a row span for the yellow square. Ideally this should be possible using just one grid. Anyway, here's the xaml:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid Background="LimeGreen">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Yellow" Width="80" Height="80" />

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I'm still stumped on answering questions 1 and 2.